# How to add results from expanse function to a single data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe, raster

I have several rasters from which I want to calculate the area with the expanse function.

The output is a 2-column data frame.

```
expanse(raster, unit="ha")
  layer     area
1     1 211761.1
```

I'm looking for a smooth way to combine these outputs into a new single-column data frame. And then add columns with more information about the rasters into it.

Comment: Try `lapply(several_rasters, expanse, unit="ha") |> do.call(what='rbind')`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer of jay the following line did the job.

```
df<-lapply(list(r1,r2,r3), expanse, unit="ha") |> do.call(what='rbind')
```